# I am getting verifyError in gson object

Tags: android, gson

My app is getting crash in one android device version is 4.4.2 and the error is

java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/gson/Gson

and the code is:-

```
public static UserData getReg(Context mContext) {
    if (ud == null) {
        try {
            PrefrencesShared shared = new PrefrencesShared(mContext);
            String sr = shared.getPrefrenceString("user");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sr);
            Type type = new TypeToken<UserData>() {
            }.getType();
            ud = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), UserData.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ud;
}
```

Comment: the error point the code

Comment: show your json for verification

Comment: add this in your build.gradle file multiDexEnabled true

Comment: i have added multiDexEnabled true but didn't get solution